# react-native link gives error for react-native-firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, react-native-firebase

I am trying to link react-native-firebase library based on the tutorial, and as soon as I run the command:

`react-native link react-native-firebase`

I get the following error:

```
Scanning folders for symlinks in 
/Users/christkhodabakhshi/projects/FlashCard/node_modules (18ms)
rnpm-install info Linking react-native-firebase ios dependency 
rnpm-install WARN ERRGROUP Group 'Libraries' does not exist in your 
Xcode project. We have created it automatically for you.
rnpm-install ERR! Something went wrong while linking. Error: Cannot 
read property 'children' of null 
 Please file an issue here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues 

Cannot read property 'children' of null
```

and the following is my package.json

```
 "expo": "^29.0.0",
 "expokit": "^1.5.0",
 "firebase": "^5.3.0",
 "react": "16.3.1",
 "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-29.0.0.tar.gz",
 "react-native-firebase": "^4.3.1",
```

Comment: Try manually adding the libraries to your project

Comment: I don't know how the manual linking would be in Android, can you drop a link here, please?